# How to add field value as Email subject in Magent2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, email, contact-form

I want to add field value as email subject in Magento2.2.5(Refer screenshot)

[image]

Here subject field is a select field, if I select option-1 value, The selected value should be the subject for the email to be sent for the contact form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it contact form?

Comment: Yes, it is contact form.

Comment: plz check my answer and let me know if it helps. !

Comment: Thank you Manashvi, it is working perfectly fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overide the email template file located at `vendor\magento\module-contact\view\frontend\email\submitted_form.html` by placing it into your custom theme at below location :

```
app\design\frontend\Custom\Theme\Magento_Contact\email\submitted_form.html
```

and change the subject like below :

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{var data.subject}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var data.comment":"Comment",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table class="message-details">
    <tr>
        <td><b>{{trans "Name"}}</b></td>
        <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>{{trans "Email"}}</b></td>
        <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>{{trans "Phone"}}</b></td>
        <td>{{var data.telephone}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><b>{{trans "Message"}}</b></p>
<p>{{var data.comment}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

**NOTE** Here `{{var data.subject}}` is used, assuming that the name of the select box in the contact us form is `subject`